# How to return HtmlCollection from Jquery selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery selection like this:

```
elements= $($('#mytab').find('form').attr('elements')).not('button');

// access elements by name
 elements['id']=1;
```

which is not working obviously :(

I need the jquery to return the collection as HtmlCollection e.g

```
$('#mytab').find('form').attr('elements')
```

My qeuestion is, is there any function available e.g like toArray() etc to 
return the collection as HtmlCollection, instead of jquery array/ object collection ?
My main objective is to access form elements by name not by index e.g

```
elements['id'], elements['name']
```

[Html Form elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/form.elements)
 Lots of confusion around elements. elements is attribute of html `form` object which is collection of all the elements in the `form`

[Here is a JSfiddle for this.](http://jsfiddle.net/AfMst/)

Comment: What about `.attr('id')`?

Comment: @DanLee , sorry if I am not clear , I need to access the form elements by NAME after filtering some form elements by element type.Which is possible if I get the collection ,as HtmlCollection

Comment: _"which is not working obviously :("_: Well `elements` is a jQuery collection, what did you expect to happen? `id` is not a property of `jQuery`.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with *name*? Do you mean the name attribute?

Comment: elements is HTML collection for form elements and has nothing to do with jquery

Comment: elements[0].attr('id', 1); ? jquery element collection is array like object

Comment: @sakhunzai I think you're making yourself a harder time than you actually need to. But what I don't understand is your goal. What are you trying to do? You sure can do everything with jQuery or vanilla JavaScript

Comment: @DanLee, yes some poeple make is harder when they do not understand it question and context, might be its my fault . a) I need to filter html form elements through jquery , b). need to access them by their name , simple ..

Comment: if you do not understand question properly , please  do not go crazy and down vote and press close etc. It is not helpful , thanks

Answer (score 1):

`elements` is a property not an attribute, you should use `prop` method instead:

```
var elements = $('#mytab').find('form').prop('elements');
```

or:

```
var elements = $('#mytab').find('form')[0].elements;
```

Well, if you want to filter input elements, you can use `get` method, there is no need to use `elements` property:

```
var elements = $('#mytab form input').get();
```

http://api.jquery.com/get/

Comment: thanks , yes you are there at first step , my next step is to filter those elements ( e.g just return input elements) and return the result as Htmlcollection , not jquery collection type

Comment: is there any way to filter form elements in simple javascript e.g how you will do this in plain javascript : `$($('#mytab').find('form').attr('elements')).not('button');` ,I need this think exactly

Comment: @sakhunzai As I said `$($('#mytab').find('form').attr('elements')).not('button')` won't work since `atrr('elements')` returns `undefined` and yes, there is a way, you are using jQuery, what's wrong with `$('#mytab form input').get();`?

Comment: `var elements = $('#mytab form input').get(); ` , after this I will not be able to select elements by name e.g `elements['name'].value`, thanks for you help however.

Comment: I need to access elements like HTMLCollection , not like an array

Comment: @sakhunzai _after this I will not be able to select elements by name_ No, `get` returns a HTMLCollection.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, there is:

```
$.makeArray($('div'));
```

This returns a array of all `div` elements on the page. Obviously, you can use any selector you want.

To get a array of elements, by their name, just use native JS:

```
document.getElementsByName('myFormElementName');
```

Comment: should I able to access form elements by their name after this  ?

Comment: No, you'll need to use native JS: `document.getElementsByName('myFormElementName')`

Comment: well my question is, is this possible with jQuery ?

Comment: Why do you want to use jQuery for this? jQuery has no `getElementsByName` function, and to build a function like that would require a somewhat ugly hack.
**Edit**: Actually, you can use: `$([name='foo'])`, but that'll only return a jQuery object instead of a array.

Comment: is there any way to filter form elements  in simple javascript e.g how you will do this in plain javascript :  `$($('#mytab').find('form').attr('elements')).not('button');`

Comment: `document.getElementById('#mytab').getElementsByTagName('form')`